# Automated splitting of css files based on ie9's selector limit

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for an automated solution for splitting my minified css files based on ie9's selector limit (take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx)).

I'm using MVC.NET, so integrating it within my bundles would be the best solution. Integrating it in my TFS Build is also ok.

I've been looking at [Bless](http://blesscss.com/), but this seems to be a node integration (perhaps I'm wrong?) and fairly difficult to integrate with .NET.

Does anybody have any experience with this ?